# setAlarmClock fails after a few hours

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm making an alarm clock application. I'm using setAlarmClock to set the time it goes off, and WakefulBroadcastReceiver to accept the set alarm.

The alarm rings perfectly when I use test it to ring after 1 minutes, or 30 minutes, even when I've kill the app. But everytime I set it to ring after 5 hours, the WakefulBroadcastReceiver no longer receive the pendingIntent

Here's my code in a global class :

```
public static void setAlarm (Context context, long timelong){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong(KEY_SET_TIME, timelong);
        editor.commit();

        myToaster(context, "Alarm will ring after " + timeCompare(timelong, System.currentTimeMillis()));

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(timelong, pendingIntent), pendingIntent);
        }
```

The WakefulBroadcastReceiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    final private String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.e(TAG, "received");
        Intent toRinger = new Intent(context, RingerActivity.class);
        toRinger.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Log.e(TAG, "Received and firing intent");
        context.startActivity(toRinger);
    }
}
```

Then, I set a mediaPlayer ring at RingerActivity.class onCreate.

Also, here's how I call the setAlarm method using a TimepickerFragment

```
public TimepickerFragment(){
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //Use the current time as the default values for the time picker
        textView = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Date d = new Date();
        int hour = d.getHours();
        int minute = d.getMinutes();

        //Create and return a new instance of TimePickerDialog
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    //onTimeSet() callback method
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute){
        Long timelong = timeToLong(hour, minute);
        Globe.setAlarm(getContext(), timelong);

        String timeString = Globe.dateToTimeString(new Date(timelong));
        String alarmInfo = getText(R.string.alarm_info) + " " + timeString;
        textView.setText(alarmInfo);
    }

public static long timeToLong(int h, int m) {
        Date d = new Date();
        d.setHours(h);
        d.setMinutes(m);
        if (d.getTime() <= System.currentTimeMillis())
            return (d.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        else
            return d.getTime();
    }
```

So, can anyone tell me why my alarm clock does not work if I set it further than 1 hour, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I've seen other answers on this topic, but still haven't found my answer. Trying to use setExactWhileIdle for SDK M made my situation even worse. It ring if I set if after 5 minutes, but wont after 15 minutes

Comment: how u r passing time for 5 hours show us

Comment: PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timelong pendingIntent);

Answer (score 0):

found it in another question here on SO, and edited my code. It works perfectly. However, I'm trying to find it again, but to no avail. So, I'm putting my working code here.

I edited my WakefulBroadCastReceiver to start a WakefulService. Then, I moved my intent to the Ringer Activity to the WakefulService.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver{

    final private String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.e(TAG, "received");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverService.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startWakefulService(context, i);
        }
    }
}
```

The wakefulService

```
public class AlarmReceiverService extends IntentService {

    public AlarmReceiverService() {
        super("AlarmReceiverService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiverService", "Service received");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, RingerActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```